# Is there a tool, or script, that can convert CSS Width/Height to the width=""/height="" equivalent on elements?

Tags: css, converters, html-email

I write html emails, and an integral part of the process is converting my CSS inline. I've looked for a while for a way to convert CSS Width/height properties into the actual email tags but to no avail.

If there is a tool that exists that performs this function, if not, is there a recommended way to achieve this goal?

Example:

```
.table_style     {width: 100%;}
.image_style img {width: 250px; height: 50px;}

<table class="table_style" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
      <td>
         <img class="image_style" alt="" src="/image.jpg" border="0">
      </td>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

the end goal would look as follows:

```
<table class="table_style" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
      <td>
         <img class="image_style" width="250" height="50" alt="" src="/image.jpg" border="0">
      </td>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: Inline `style=""` attributes also work fine.  https://github.com/SLaks/Styliner

Comment: @SLaks That's what I used to think, but apparently, at least some email clients have troubles with at least some style properties. I think the OP is better off with as many attributes as possible.

Comment: Inline style="" works fine on some, but not all clients for the width and height properties. It's a better practice in email to put them in the actual tag itself. (See example two on the main post).

Comment: It can be done using PHP. I'm not aware of a turn-key solution however.

Comment: It can be done with many programming languages. In fact, I'd go so far as to claim it could be done in XSLT.

Comment: @MrLister: Most email clients do not support things like floats or CSS `position`.  All of them should (AFAIK?) support `style="width: x"`.

Comment: I checked the inline optimization tool on the Email on Acid testing service and it doesn't use the old style attributes. Its inline `style=""`

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools made for this exact use: "inlining" CSS into the body of HTML emails. It does width, height as well as any other properties you have in your CSS declarations.

Here are a couple:

[MailChimp CSS Inliner Tool](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)

[Campaign Monitor CSS Inliner](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/inliner/)